# A Sound interface which listens on the microphone IO port for activity?

Tags: c++, microphone, audio

Since so much open source is out there:

Are there C++ libraries which might have the Microphone Port listening functionality already built in and working:

Had to ask because that is the nature of the modern world so much has already been done. i have a whole bunch of other sound things to do And the QT IDE looks like the place to start, it cane with a bunch of lovely libraries with a wide range of functionality

Thanks * Regards
TheD
Los Angeles

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Many audio libraries are available that can input sound from a variety of different sources. A very popular open source library that supports multiple platforms is PortAudio. Qt also provides its own cross-platform audio functionality.